# Create Dynamic UI (Input Form) from API Response in a Mobile App Developed Using OutSystems Platform

Tags: outsystems

**I am searching for how a dynamic UI (or input form to submit user inputs) can be created in *OutSystems* (for my mobile application) depending upon the response of some API; that tells what kind of input elements are to be included in the form, in some order like TextView, EditText, Button, ImageView, Button and so on.** This is because in my application a scenario is being raised in which there are several companies that provide forms to be filled by several employees and the employees can fill the form of the company in which they are interested (they may or may not be working in the same company) *and each form is different (with different input elements respectively)* and the API is hit with the logged-in access token (of the employee) and the company name whose form he has opted to fill with the form number/name that he has selected to fill (as each company may offer different variants of forms to be filled respectively). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

**Note: I am specifically talking about building the above scenario in an application that is developed using the *OutSystems Platform*.**

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: you can *probably* do it if you use the List widget along with some if conditions - which would then be a huge pain to maintain.

Other than this, I'm not sure if it is possible at the time.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you would bypass some of the great stuff that Outsystems provides.
You might want to go for a javascript-solution where you retrieve and post the data via your own webservices on that specific screen...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a block for List. This block would be having all the possible input widgets like InputText, DropDown or anything else. These widgets would be encapsulated into nested if-else blocks. The condition for the if-else blocks would be the type of the input fields. If it matches a specific type of widget then it will be visible else it will be invisible. 
This way you can pass the list response into the List widget and one item of list response to the listItem block.
I hope it gives you a good idea how to implement this.
Let me know if you have other queries.